# regedit dialog not opening

Tags: registry, regedit

I am trying to open regedit from run dialog on Winxp. I tried to lauch it from alternative places such as Task Manager, IE etc. I am running as admin

Forums reveal that's it's a virus.  but nothing concrete to get it working

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly a programming question, so this probably isn't the place for this...but try to boot in Safe Mode without Networking and opening the registry from there.

Cheers,
Eric

Comment: Ok, I was not aware that it's only programming.

Comment: It isn't only programming related, just the majority are programming questions. You should tag it with 'not-programming-related' though. (as I have now done)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a virus preventing you starting regedit.exe, try making a copy of regedit.exe with a different filename.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Start->Run->**gpedit.msc**

Enter "Group Policy/User Configuration/Administrative Templates/System".

Check "prevent the access regedit"

May be this setting is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me once...
simply got to your windows dir: eg: c:\windows
You will probably find that there's no regedit.exe!!
simply copy it from any other pc and paste it there!!!